# vfmadd231ps Floating Point Exception c0000090

Tags: assembly, x86, windbg, avx, fma

What is the problem with the vfmadd231ps instruction which throws a floating point Exception?

```
    00007ff9`88f05108 62b26558b81482  vfmadd231ps zmm2,zmm3,dword bcst [rdx+r8*4] ds:00000220`7de9dc00=00000000
    
    0:112> .exr -1
        ExceptionAddress: 00007ff988f05108 
           ExceptionCode: c0000090
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        NumberParameters: 2
           Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
           Parameter[1]: 0000000000001923
        
        
    0:112> rZ
                zmm0=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                zmm1=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                zmm2=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                zmm3=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        

0:112> r zmm2:f
zmm2=           0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
0:112> r zmm3:f
zmm3=           0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
0:112> r zmm3:ub
zmm3=           0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
0:112> r zmm2:ub
zmm2=           0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0

    0:112> db 0220`7de9dc00 L0x40
    00000220`7de9dc00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    00000220`7de9dc10  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    00000220`7de9dc20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    00000220`7de9dc30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    
            
mxcsr=1923
```

According to https://help.totalview.io/previous_releases/2019/html/index.html#page/Reference_Guide/Intelx86MXSCRRegister.html

the flag 0x1923 indicates

- 0x1 Invalid Operation Flag
- 0x2 Denormal Flag
- 0x20 Precision Flag
- 0x1000 Precision Mask
- 0x100 Denormal Mask
- 0x800 Underflow Mask

Which value of the register is responsible for throwing an exception and what is wrong with the inputs? I am no AVX expert. To me Fused Multiply Add with all zeros looks ok to me.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I have added the memory location.

Comment: What's in memory at that address?  Perhaps a vector with a NaN element?  That's the 3rd source operand, one of the multipliers.   The x87 st0..st7 and x87 fp control registers are totally irrelevant to this, BTW.  But your zmm2 and 3 dump shows that those registers were all-zero.  (sorry, reposted to edit after you replied)

Comment: @PeterCords: You mean at 220`7de9dc00? I have added that. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Are you sure the register values are exactly 0, not shown as rounded?  Those don't look like hex dumps the way memory is.  But a subnormal wouldn't explain getting an Invalid operation.  Can you make a [mcve] of a program that sets MXCSR and produces this exception with the same register values you're seeing?  And BTW, actually only the first dword of memory matters; it's an AVX-512 broadcast memory source.  Using non-standard syntax, `dword bcst` instead of `dword [...] {1to16}`

Comment: @PeterCordes: I will get to that next week. If I do not change the inputs I could change the mxcsr flags. These are non standard. The default should be 1F80h as far as I have found so far. This is an regression issue after a compiler switch so I am not sure what did change the FPU Control register to throw an exception. That needs more debugging where that one comes from.

Comment: Right, the default FP environment has all exception masked.  (For both the x87 control word, and the SSE/AVX MXCSR, which are independent FP environments.)